# Diferença entre tabela temporária e variável tipo table

Tags: sql, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados, tabela-temporária

No *SQLServer* existe os recursos de tabela temporária e variável do tipo table.

Qual seria o  mais vantajoso ou a melhor opção para colocar em uma *procedure* que insere a consulta que foi retornada de um *SELECT*, podendo armazenar em média de 2 mil registros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma tabela temporária é uma tabela real e pode fazer tudo o que uma tabela normal pode, o SQL Server fará todas otimizações possíveis nela, principalmente se tiver índices secundários, pode estar em transações, respeita as configurações do seu banco de dados enfim, a única diferença da tabla normal é que ela será descartada no final da sessão do usuário ou de todos usuários que a usam.

Variáveis com tabelas podem ser mais fáceis de usar em alguns cenários como *stored procedures* e funções. Pode até ajudar na performance deles em si (não da execução da consulta). Mas você quase não usa essas coisas, certo? Ou você é DBA? :P Mas tem coisas que é mais difícil fazer com este recurso. A variável é um recurso de programação no banco dados, não costuma ser usada na manipulação normal do banco de dados, é um instrumento de código. Não use para tabelas com mais do que centenas de linhas. Pense nela mais como um *array* um pouco mais sofisticado do que uma tabela mesmo.

Como cada uma tem uma função elas oferecem mais vantagens no cenário adequado. Curiosamente um recurso feito pra programadores costuma ser mais usado por DBAs que gostam de jogar código dentro do banco de dados, E o recurso mais feito para o banco de dados em si é preferido pelos programadores já que eles programam fora do banco de dados.

- [Documentação do *table type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- Uma [resposta bem mais completa](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16385/41) no DBA.SE.
- [Blog da Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/tempdb-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Entre as tabelas temporárias e as variáveis do tipo table no SQL Server, a escolha ideal para o seu cenário depende das necessidades específicas da sua aplicação e do desempenho desejado. Vamos comparar as duas opções:

**1. Tabelas temporárias (local ou global):**

- São armazenadas no tempdb;
- Possuem estatísticas que podem otimizar as consultas;
- Podem ser indexadas;
- Permitem ações de DDL (como ALTER TABLE) após a criação;
- Tabelas temporárias locais (#tabela) possuem escopo limitado à sessão
  atual, enquanto tabelas temporárias globais (##tabela) são acessíveis
  a todas as sessões, mas são menos comuns e não recomendadas para uso
  frequente.

**2. Variáveis do tipo table:**

- São armazenadas na memória, o que geralmente é mais rápido que o
  tempdb;
- Não possuem estatísticas, o que pode resultar em planos de execução
  menos eficientes;
- Podem ser indexadas apenas na sua definição (índices inline);
- Não permitem ações de DDL após a criação;
- Possuem escopo limitado ao lote atual.

No seu caso, como você mencionou que a procedure insere a consulta retornada de um SELECT e armazena cerca de 2.000 registros, você pode começar usando uma variável do tipo table. Ela deve ser suficiente para o volume de dados mencionado e pode oferecer um desempenho melhor, já que os dados são armazenados na memória.

No entanto, se você enfrentar problemas de desempenho ou perceber que o plano de execução não é eficiente, considere usar uma tabela temporária local. Isso permitirá que o SQL Server utilize estatísticas e otimize o plano de execução. Além disso, se você precisar de mais flexibilidade para modificar a estrutura da tabela ou indexação, a tabela temporária será a melhor opção.

Em resumo, comece com a variável do tipo table e monitore o desempenho. Se necessário, mude para uma tabela temporária local para aproveitar os recursos adicionais e a otimização do plano de execução.